# Is there a formula for $\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{m j}{m}$, where $m$ is an integer?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Is there a formula for $\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{m j}{m}$, where $m$ is an integer?

It's similar to the Hockey-stick-identity $$ \sum_{j=1}^{mn} \binom{j}{m} = \binom{mn+1}{m+1}, $$ but now we only want to consider every $m$-th summand. Is there a formula or an upper bound (that's better than $\binom{mn+1}{m+1}$)?

Comment: I don't know if there are versions of the Wilf-Zeilberger algorithm available online, but that test will clearly tell you if this expression has a closed hypergeometric form or not. Of course, that doesn't say anything about what bounds might be available.

Comment: `f@m_ := Sum[Binomial[m*j, m], {j, 1, n}];
f /@ Range[10] // Map[TraditionalForm, #] & // TableForm`

for m=1..=3 the result is $\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{2} n (n+1) \\
 \frac{1}{6} n (n+1) (4 n-1) \\
 \frac{1}{8} n (n+1) (3 n-2) (3 n+1) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer**

This answer does not contain a closed form, only ideas and some stronger upper bound than the one provided in the original question.

**Combinatorial Argument**

You are asked to choose $m+1$ unordered distinct numbers from $1,2,...,mn+m$. What is the number of possibilities where the largest chosen number satisfies $x_{max}\equiv 1 \mod{m}$?

Let the largest chosen number is $mj+1$ with $j\in\{1,...,n\}$, then the remaining numbers must be chosen from $1,2,...,mj$. The number of possibilities are then given by the original equation:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{mj}{m}
$$

**Upper Bound**

The number of sets with largest number $x_{max}\equiv k\mod{m}$, but we use $m$ instead of $0$ here for convenience, is given below:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{mj+k-1}{m} \geq
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{mj}{m}
$$

If we sum over all possible integer $k$, we obtain all possible $m+1$ chosen numbers out of $mn+m$ integers:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{m}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{mj+k-1}{m}
=
\binom{mn+m}{m+1}
$$
Therefore, one can see that there is an upper bound:

$$
\frac{1}{m}
\binom{mn+m}{m+1}
\geq
\sum_{j=1}^{n}\binom{mj}{m}
$$

**Remarks**

Hope others can also give their thoughts and ideas. Also hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: This is definitely a nice combinatorial argument, thank you!

Comment: You inspired me and $+1$

Comment: This is essentially a left endpoint approximation; presumably you could do better by using an appropriate trapezoid rule?

Answer (score 4):

Im not sure about a closed form for the sum, but for fixed $m$, we have an asymptotic formula
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{mj}{m}\sim\frac{m^m}{(m+1)!}n^{m+1}.$$
To show this we can use the generating function of $(a_n)=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{mj}{m}\right)$.
\begin{align*}
f(z)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{mj}{m}z^n\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{n=j}^\infty\binom{mj}{m}z^n\\
&=\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\binom{mj}{m}z^j\\
&=\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(mj)(mj-1)\cdots(mj-m+1)}{m!}z^j.
\end{align*}
Now considering $f(z^m),$ we have
\begin{align*}
f(z^m)&=\frac{1}{1-z^m}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(mj)(mj-1)\cdots(mj-m+1)}{m!}z^{mj}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-z^m}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{z^m}{m!}\frac{d^m}{dz^m}z^{mj}\\
&=\frac{z^m}{1-z^m}\cdot\frac{1}{m!}\frac{d^m}{dz^m}\left(\frac{z^m}{1-z^m}\right)\\
&=\frac{z^m}{1-z^m}\cdot\frac{1}{m!}\frac{d^m}{dz^m}\left(-1+\frac{1}{1-z^m}\right)\\
&=\frac{z^m}{1-z^m}\cdot\frac{1}{m!}\frac{d^m}{dz^m}\left(\frac{1}{1-z^m}\right)\\
&=\frac{z^m}{z^m-1}\cdot\frac{1}{m!}\frac{d^m}{dz^m}\left(\frac{1}{z^m-1}\right)\\
\end{align*}
Using the method of partial fractions, we have
$$\frac{1}{z^m-1}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{r_j}{z-r_j}.$$
Where $r_j=\exp\left(2i\pi j/m\right)$. Hence
\begin{align*}
f(z^m)&=\frac{z^m}{z^m-1}\cdot\frac{1}{m!}\cdot\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{r_j(-1)^mm!}{\left(z-r_j\right)^{m+1}}\\
&=\frac{z^m}{z^m-1}\cdot\frac{(-1)^m}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{r_j}{\left(z-r_j\right)^{m+1}}.
\end{align*}
And $$f(z)=\frac{z}{z-1}\cdot\frac{(-1)^m}{m}\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{r_j}{\left(z^{1/m}-r_j\right)^{m+1}}.$$
I claim that $f$ is a rational function, to show this, we will show by induction that the $k$th derivative of $1/(z^m-1)$ takes the form $z^{m-k}S_k(z^m)/T_k(z^m)$ for some polynomials $S_k$, $T_k$. Indeed for $k=0$ we may take $S_0(z^m)=1$ and $T_0(z^m)=z^m(z^m-1)$, now assume that the $r$th derivative of $1/(z^m-1)$ takes this form for some $r\geq0$ and consider
\begin{align*}
\frac{d^{r+1}}{dz^{r+1}}\left(\frac{1}{z^m-1}\right)&=\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{z^{m-r}S_r(z^m)}{T_r(z^m)}\right)\\
&=\frac{z^{m-r-1}((m-r)S_r(z^m)T_r(z^m)+mz^m(T_r(z^m)S_r^\prime(z^m)-S_r(z^m)T_r^\prime(z^m)))}{T_r(z^m)^2}
\end{align*}
This is of the expected form and so the result follows by induction. Therefore the $m$th derivative of $1/(z^m-1)$ is a rational function of $z^m$ from which it follows that $f(z^m)$ is a rational function of $z^m$ and hence $f(z)$ is a rational function of $z$.

If $\alpha$ is a pole of $f$, then $\alpha^{1/m}$ is a pole of $f(z^m)$ and hence $\alpha^{1/m}$ is an $m$th root of unity. It follows that $\alpha=1$ and that $f$ is of the form $P(z)/(z-1)^r$ for some polynomial $P$. We have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\rightarrow1}\left((z-1)^{m+2}f(z)\right)&=\lim_{z\rightarrow1}\left(z\cdot\frac{(-1)^m}{m}\sum_{j=1}^mr_j\left(\frac{z-1}{z^{1/m}-r_j}\right)^{m+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^m}{m}\lim_{z\rightarrow1}\left(\left(\frac{z-1}{z^{1/m}-1}\right)^{m+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^m}{m}\cdot m^{m+1}\\
&=(-1)^mm^m
\end{align*}
This limit exists and is non-zero, so $r=m+2$ and $P(1)=(-1)^mm^m$. A [theorem](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Asymptotic_Estimates_of_the_Coefficients_of_Meromorphic_Functions) of Sedgewick now gives us an asymptotic formula for $a_n$, namely
$$a_n\sim\frac{(-1)^{m+2}(m+2)P(1)}{(m+2)!}n^{m+1}=\frac{m^m}{(m+1)!}n^{m+1}.$$

Comment: This is a very nice solution and $+1$ for sure. For $m=123$ and $n=45$, it gives $7.565\times 10^{254}$ instead of $5.665\times 10^{254}$. I tried to do something with hypergeomtric function but I failed. By the way, *Welcome to the site !*. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from @Rezha Adrian Tanuharja's upper bound
$$A=\frac 1m \binom{m (n+1)}{m+1}=\frac{n\, \Gamma (m(n+1))}{\Gamma (m+2) \,\,\Gamma (m n+1)}$$n for large values of $m$

$$\log(A)=((n+1) \log (n+1)-n \log (n))\,m+\frac 12  \log \left(\frac{n (n+1)}{2 \pi  m^3}\right)-$$
$$\frac{13 n^2+13 n+1}{12 m n (n+1)}+\frac{1}{2 m^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^3}\right)$$

Trying for $m=123$ and $n=45$, the above truncated expansion gives
$$\log(A)=588.248 \quad\implies\quad A=2.97012\times 10^{255} $$ while the summation would give $5.66477\times 10^{254}$.

This looks pretty good.

Comment: Whoa, that's really nice!

Answer (score 2):

We can reinterpret Rezha Adrian Tanuharja's answer as follows: for fixed $m$, we have the function $\binom{x}{m}$ is increasing as a function of $x \in \mathbb{N}$; therefore $$m \cdot \binom{jm}{m} \leq \binom{jm}{m} + \binom{jm + 1}{m} + \ldots + \binom{jm + m - 1}{m}$$  for any $j \geq 0$.  (And then substitute and use the hockey stick identity.)  But in fact for fixed $m$ we also have that $\binom{x}{m}$ is *convex* as a function of $x \in \mathbb{N}$; therefore $$m \cdot \binom{jm}{m} \leq \binom{jm - \lceil m/2\rceil + 1}{m} + \binom{jm - \lceil m/2\rceil + 2}{m} + \ldots + \binom{jm + \lfloor m/2\rfloor}{m}$$
for any $j \geq 0$.  Consequently we can improve Rezha Adrian Tanuharja's answer slightly to $$
\sum_{j = 1}^n \binom{jm}{m} \leq \frac{1}{m} \binom{nm + \lfloor m/2\rfloor + 1}{m + 1}.$$